# PostInstall Script Fails when installed in Sandbox

Tags: app-development, postinstall

My app sends an email to the installer via a PostInstall script, but whenever someone tries to install my app in a Sandbox, the script fails.

I'm wondering if Sandboxes require different setup?  Could this also fail if Email Deliverability is set to "No Access"? (Standard in SF sandboxes now)

Thanks!

Ben

Comment: I think thats the reason. Email Deliverability

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've got this one, if the email deliverability is off (which is the norm for sandboxes) you're apps email won't go anywhere.  You might look at using a call out instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Go to Setup --> Email Deliverability --> Access Level.
```

If you are sending email outside salesforce then set Access Level to 'All email'& save configuration.

By default in sandboxes, Access level is set to 'System Email only'.
So post installation script fails & so package installation/upgrade.